# Issue while creating an indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create an indexed view from 50 different tables from same database using UNION ALL. 
I tried using the following query which is throwing an error,

```
USE ABC
GO
CREATE VIEW QID_Consolidated_View([ID],[METRIC],[PT_FIRST_NM],[PT_LAST_NM],[D1],[D2],[D3],[RE1],[RE2],[N1],[N2],[N3],[PE1],[RD],[RN],[PD],[PN],[RD_Calc],[RN_Calc],[PD_Calc],[PN_Calc],[Comments])

WITH SCHEMABINDING

AS
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY METRIC ) AS ID,[METRIC],[PT_FIRST_NM],[PT_LAST_NM],[D1],[D2],[D3],[RE1],[N1],[N2],[N3],[PE1],[RD],[RN],[PD],[PN],[RD_Calc],[RN_Calc],[PD_Calc],[PN_Calc],[Comments] from
         (
        -------------------------------001-------------------------------
         SELECT 'QID 001' as METRIC,[PT_FIRST_NM],[PT_LAST_NM],cast([D1] as int) as D1,cast([D2] as char(4)) as D2,cast([D3] as int) as D3,cast([RE1] as int) as [RE1]
              ,cast([N1] as int) as N1,cast([N2] as int) as [N2],cast([N3] as int) as N3,cast([PE1] as int) as [PE1]
              ,cast([RD] as int) as [RD],cast([RN] as int) as [RN],cast([PD] as int) as [PD],cast([PN] as int) as [PN],cast([RD_Calc] as int) as [RD_Calc]
              ,cast([RN_Calc] as int) as [RN_Calc] ,cast([PD_Calc] as int) as [PD_Calc],cast([PN_Calc] as int) as [PN_Calc],[Comments]
        FROM dbo.[001]
        UNION ALL
        -------------------------------002-------------------------------
        SELECT 'QID 012' as METRIC,[PT_FIRST_NM],[PT_LAST_NM],cast([D1] as int) as D1,cast([D2] as char(4)) as D2,cast([D3] as int) as D3,cast([RE1] as int) as [RE1]
              ,cast([N1] as int) as N1,cast([N2] as int) as [N2],cast([N3] as int) as N3,cast([PE1] as int) as [PE1]
              ,cast([RD] as int) as [RD],cast([RN] as int) as [RN],cast([PD] as int) as [PD],cast([PN] as int) as [PN],cast([RD_Calc] as int) as [RD_Calc]
              ,cast([RN_Calc] as int) as [RN_Calc] ,cast([PD_Calc] as int) as [PD_Calc],cast([PN_Calc] as int) as [PN_Calc],[Comments]
        FROM dbo.[002]
        UNION ALL
        -------------------------------003-------------------------------
        SELECT 'QID 014' as METRIC,[PT_FIRST_NM],[PT_LAST_NM],cast([D1] as int) as D1,cast([D2] as char(4)) as D2,cast([D3] as int) as D3,cast([RE1] as int) as [RE1]
              ,cast([N1] as int) as N1,cast([N2] as int) as [N2],cast([N3] as int) as N3,cast([PE1] as int) as [PE1]
              ,cast([RD] as int) as [RD],cast([RN] as int) as [RN],cast([PD] as int) as [PD],cast([PN] as int) as [PN],cast([RD_Calc] as int) as [RD_Calc]
              ,cast([RN_Calc] as int) as [RN_Calc] ,cast([PD_Calc] as int) as [PD_Calc],cast([PN_Calc] as int) as [PN_Calc],[Comments]
        FROM dbo.[003]

        )
    A

    GO

    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
        IDX_QID_Consolidated_View_ID ON dbo.QID_Consolidated_View(ID)
```

And the error is :

> Cannot create index on view "ABC.dbo.QID_Consolidated_View" because it
>   references derived table "A" (defined by SELECT statement in FROM
>   clause). Consider removing the reference to the derived table or not
>   indexing the view.

Could someone please help me in fixing this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have used `schemabinding` cant create index on computed column

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "Additional Requirements" section in this [BOL link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) which lists out what you can and can't do with an Index View.  Derived Tables are not permitted

[image]